# Android bringing a layout on and off the screen

Tags: android, android-standout

Im trying to make a task manager app. A simple swipe right from the left side of the screen should bring up the task manager, and a swipe left should hide the task manager. How would i accomplish this? I have two views, h an b. When i swipe h to the right, view b should pop up. When i swipe h left, view b should dissapear. For right now when you swipe left view b dissapears. However when you swipe right, view b does not pop back up.
package wei.mark.example;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import wei.mark.standout.StandOutWindow;
import wei.mark.standout.constants.StandOutFlags;
import wei.mark.standout.ui.Window;

public class SimpleWindow extends StandOutWindow {

private View h, b, tex1;
//private TextView tex1;
private float x1, x2;
private int x = 300;
private int y = 1920;
static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 150;


@Override
public String getAppName() {
    return "SimpleWindow";
}

@Override
public int getAppIcon() {
    return android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel;
}

@Override
public void createAndAttachView(int id,  FrameLayout frame) {
    // create a new layout from body.xml
    tex1 = frame.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    b = frame.findViewById(R.id.bruh);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple, frame, true);
    h = frame.findViewById(R.id.touchwiz);
    h.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this){
        public void onSwipeTop() {
            Toast.makeText(SimpleWindow.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            Toast.makeText(SimpleWindow.this, "right",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            Toast.makeText(SimpleWindow.this, "left",       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     / /Hide view b
            b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        public void onSwipeBottom() {
            Toast.makeText(SimpleWindow.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });



}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x1 = event.getX();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            x2 = event.getX();
            float deltaX = x2 - x1;
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "left2right swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
            }
            else
            {
                // consider as something else - a screen tap for example
            }
            break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

// the window will be centered
@Override
public StandOutLayoutParams getParams(int id, Window window) {
    return new StandOutLayoutParams(id, x, y,
            StandOutLayoutParams.LEFT, StandOutLayoutParams.CENTER);

}


// move the window by dragging the view
@Override
public int getFlags(int id) {

    return super.getFlags(id)
            | StandOutFlags.FLAG_WINDOW_FOCUSABLE_DISABLE | StandOutFlags.FL;
}

@Override
public String getPersistentNotificationMessage(int id) {
    return "Click to close the SimpleWindow";
}

@Override
public Intent getPersistentNotificationIntent(int id) {
    return StandOutWindow.getCloseIntent(this, SimpleWindow.class, id);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, because the b view is still on layout, but you can't see it. You should use View.GONE instead of View.INVISIBLE.

```
View.GONE This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

View.INVISIBLE This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.
```